# A Child Process That Calls Exit() But Does Not Become A Zombie

Tags: c, process, operating-system

For learning purpose, I wrote a piece of code to generate zombie processes. Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t pid;

int main() {
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    exit(0);
  } else {
   printf("the child process is %d", pid);
    sleep(20);
  }
}
```

In my assumption, the codes above should behave in such a way: the child process receive `pid` of 0 and `exit` with status code 0; the parent process receive `pid` of the child process and print it out and go to sleep for 20 seconds. Because the parent process does not call `wait` when the child process `exit`, the child process should be zombie for about 20 seconds.

However, when I run the codes, it waits for about 20 seconds and print out the child process's pid. In the 20 seconds, the child process does not appear in `ps -l` as a zombie process.

Can someone tell me what makes the difference between my understanding of the codes and its actual behavior?

P.S. I am using Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: Try adding a new line "\n" to your printf... stdout is buffered.

Comment: adding "\n" helps to print out the message, thank you! However, the child process still does not become zombie.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here.  The first is that you don't have a newline (`\n`) at the end of your `printf` string.  Since stdout is line buffered, the output won't be flushed from the output buffer unless you either print a newline or you explicitly flush the stream.

So add a newline and it should print right away:

```
printf("the child process is %d\n", pid);
```

The main reason you aren't seeing the child pid has to do with how you're using the `ps` command.  Assuming you're calling `ps` from a different shell that the one that runs this code, `ps -l` only shows processes from session running the command.  So processes started from other sessions / shells won't appear.

If you use the `-e` option (i.e. `ps -el` or `ps -ef`), this will show you the full list of processes in the system.  Then you should be able to see the zombie process.

Answer (score 0):

I have no access until tomorrow to a MAC OS system, but your program **successfully** creates a zombie process in linux systems.  I have modified your sample code to add a message when the parent process exits, and the already commented `\n` char to end properly the line and produce output at the point of `printf()` call:

## zombie.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t pid;

int main() {
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    exit(0);
  } else {
    printf("the child process is %d\n", pid);
    sleep(20);
    printf("exit();\n");
  }
}
```

And the output in linux is:

```
$ zombie &
[1] 5781
the child process is 5786

$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2569 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 5781 pts/0    00:00:00 zombie
 5786 pts/0    00:00:00 zombie <defunct>   <-- this is the zombie.
 5795 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

$ exit();  <-- zombie program finishing.
```

On FreeBSD (and MAC OS is very similar to it) the thing goes as:

```
$ zombie &
[1] 7326
the child process is 7329
$ ps
  PID TT  STAT       TIME COMMAND
 7281  0  Ss      0:00,18 -bash (bash)
 7326  0  S       0:00,02 zombie
 7329  0  Z       0:00,00 <defunct>  <-- this is the zombie.
 7335  0  R+      0:00,01 ps
$ exit();  <-- zombie program finishing.
```

Tomorrow I'll be able to do the same in a Mac OS X system, and include a third system that creates zombie processes.

Comment: Thank you! Actually `ps child_id` displays the zombie process, but it does not appear when I just `ps`.